# Можно ли разделить в таймере на JavaScript секунды, минуты и т.д. на составные части?

Tags: javascript

Использую следующий скрипт таймера обратного отсчёта:

**HTML:** `<div id="timer1">[clock1]</div>`

**JavaScript:**

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  StartCountDown("timer1","07/31/2013 00:00")

  function StartCountDown(myDiv,myTargetDate)
  {
    var dthen   = new Date(myTargetDate);
    var dnow    = new Date();
    ddiff       = new Date(dthen-dnow);
    gsecs       = Math.floor(ddiff.valueOf()/1000);
    CountBack(myDiv,gsecs);
  }

  function Calcage(secs, num1, num2)
  {
    s = ((Math.floor(secs/num1))%num2).toString();
    if (s.length < 2) 
    {   
      s = "0" + s;
    }
    return (s);
  }

  function CountBack(myDiv, secs)
  {
    var DisplayStr;
    var DisplayFormat = "%%D%% %%H%% %%M%% %%S%%";
    DisplayStr = DisplayFormat.replace(/%%D%%/g,    Calcage(secs,86400,100000));
    DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%H%%/g,       Calcage(secs,3600,24));
    DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%M%%/g,       Calcage(secs,60,60));
    DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%S%%/g,       Calcage(secs,1,60));
    if(secs > 0)
    {   
      document.getElementById(myDiv).innerHTML = DisplayStr;
      setTimeout("CountBack('" + myDiv + "'," + (secs-1) + ");", 990);
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById(myDiv).innerHTML = "Auction Over";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Нужно сделать, чтобы каждая цифра таймера была в отдельном диве. Например 16 минут - это 1 в одном диве и 6 в другом. В связи с этим вопрос: можно ли разделить вывод часов, минут, секунд, дней на отдельные цифры?

Вид таймера:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вместо:

```
setTimeout("CountBack('" + myDiv + "'," + (secs-1) + ");", 990);
```

Лучше используйте анонимную функцию:

```
setTimeout(function (){CountBack(myDiv, secs - 1);}, 990);
```

**Вариант А (верстка задана вручную):**

[image: Вариант Б]

Посмотреть рабочий пример на **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/as7Nt/1/)**

**html**

```
<div id="timer1">
    <div id="timer-header">До конца акции осталось:</div>
    <div id="days">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
        <div class="delimiter">:</div>
        <div id="title-days">дни</div>
    </div>
    <div id="hours">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
        <div class="delimiter">:</div>
        <div id="title-hours">часы</div>
    </div>
    <div id="minutes">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
        <div class="delimiter">:</div>
        <div id="title-minutes">минуты</div>
    </div>
    <div id="seconds">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
        <div id="title-seconds">секунды</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#timer1 {
    display:table-cell;
}
#timer1 > div:first-child {
    margin:0;
}
#timer1 div {
    display:inline-block;
}
#timer-header {
    display:block!important;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    text-align:center;
}
#timer1 div[id^="title-"] {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:-7px;
    width:100%;
}
#timer1 #title-seconds {
    margin:0;
}
.left, .right, .delimiter {
    font-size:32px;
}
.left, .right {
    background-color:#61890C;
    color:white;
    padding:5px;
}
.left {
    margin-right:2px;
}
.delimiter {
    padding-left:0;
}
```

**javascript**

```
StartCountDown("timer1", "07/31/2013 00:00");

function StartCountDown(myDiv, myTargetDate) {
    var dthen = new Date(myTargetDate);
    var dnow = new Date();
    ddiff = new Date(dthen - dnow);
    gsecs = Math.floor(ddiff.valueOf() / 1000);
    CountBack(myDiv, gsecs);
}

function Calcage(secs, num1, num2) {
    s = ((Math.floor(secs / num1)) % num2).toString();
    if (s.length < 2) {
        s = "0" + s;
    }
    return (s);
}

function CountBack(myDiv, secs) {
    var timeArr = [],
        holder;
    if (secs > 0) {
        timeArr.days = Calcage(secs, 86400, 100000).split('');
        timeArr.hours = Calcage(secs, 3600, 24).split('');
        timeArr.minutes = Calcage(secs, 60, 60).split('');
        timeArr.seconds = Calcage(secs, 1, 60).split('');

        Object.keys(timeArr).map(function (key) {
            holder = document.getElementById(key);
            for (var i = 0; i < holder.childNodes.length; ++i) {
                switch (holder.childNodes[i].className) {
                    case "left":
                        holder.childNodes[i].innerHTML = timeArr[key][0];
                        break;
                    case "right":
                        holder.childNodes[i].innerHTML = timeArr[key][2];
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            CountBack(myDiv, secs - 1);
        }, 990);
    } else {
        document.getElementById(myDiv).innerHTML = "Auction Over";
    }
}
```

**Вариант Б (верстка генерируется скриптом):**

[image: Вариант Б]

Посмотреть рабочий пример на **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/BDtJy/6/)**

**html**

```
<div id="timer1"></div>
```

**css**

```
#timer1 {
    display:table-cell;
}
#timer1 > div {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#timer1 > div:first-child {
    margin: 0;
}
#timer1 div {
    display:inline-block;
}
#timer-header {
    display:block!important;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    text-align:center;
}
#timer1 div[id^="title-"] {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:-7px;
    width:100%;
}
#timer1 #title-seconds {
    margin:0;
}
.left, .right, .delimiter {
    font-size:32px;
}
.left, .right {
    background-color:#61890C;
    color:white;
    padding:5px;
}
.left {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.delimiter {
    padding-left:5px;
}
```

**javascript**

```
//Создаем заголовок для таймера
createElements("timer1", "timer-header", false, true);

//Создаем блоки, которые будут содержать [дни, часы, минуты, секунды]
//Блоки будут созданы внутри элемента с id "timer1"
["days", "hours", "minutes", "seconds"].forEach(function (id) {
    createElements("timer1", id, false, true);

    //Для каждого блока [дни, часы, минуты, секунды]
    //Создаем дочерние блоки
    //Они будут содержать левую и правую цифру соответственно
    ["left", "right"].forEach(function (child_id) {
        createElements(id, child_id, true, true);
    });

    //Создаем блоки для разделителей
    if (id !== "seconds") {
        createElements(id, 'delimiter', true, true);
    }

    //Создаем подписи для значений
    createElements(id, 'title-' + id, false, true);
});

//Задаем заголовок
var header = document.getElementById('timer-header');
header.innerHTML = "До конца акции осталось:";

//Выставляем разделители (в примере двоеточие)
var delimiter = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('delimiter'));
delimiter.forEach(function (div) {
    div.innerHTML = ":";
});

//Задаем подписи к значениям таймера
var days = document.getElementById('title-days');
var hours = document.getElementById('title-hours');
var minutes = document.getElementById('title-minutes');
var seconds = document.getElementById('title-seconds');
days.innerHTML = "дни";
hours.innerHTML = "часы";
minutes.innerHTML = "минуты";
seconds.innerHTML = "секунды";

StartCountDown("timer1", "07/31/2013 00:00");

function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

//++ родительский элемент;
//++ идентификатор блока (берется из обрабатываемого массива);
//++ true - class="идентификатор блока"; false - id="идентификатор блока";
//++ true - СОЗДАТЬ ВНУТРИ родителя; false - ПРИКРЕПИТЬ ПОСЛЕ родителя
function createElements(parent_id, id, create_class, create_child) {
    create_class = typeof create_class !== 'undefined' ? !! create_class : false;
    create_child = typeof create_child !== 'undefined' ? !! create_child : false;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var parent = document.getElementById(parent_id);
    if (create_class) {
        div.className = id;
    } else {
        div.id = id;
    }
    if (create_child) {
        parent.appendChild(div);
    } else {
        insertAfter(parent, div);
    }
}

function StartCountDown(myDiv, myTargetDate) {
    var dthen = new Date(myTargetDate);
    var dnow = new Date();
    ddiff = new Date(dthen - dnow);
    gsecs = Math.floor(ddiff.valueOf() / 1000);
    CountBack(myDiv, gsecs);
}

function Calcage(secs, num1, num2) {
    s = ((Math.floor(secs / num1)) % num2).toString();
    if (s.length < 2) {
        s = "0" + s;
    }
    return (s);
}

function CountBack(myDiv, secs) {
    var timeArr = [],
        holder;
    if (secs > 0) {
        timeArr.days = Calcage(secs, 86400, 100000).split('');
        timeArr.hours = Calcage(secs, 3600, 24).split('');
        timeArr.minutes = Calcage(secs, 60, 60).split('');
        timeArr.seconds = Calcage(secs, 1, 60).split('');

        Object.keys(timeArr).map(function (key) {
            holder = document.getElementById(key);
            for (var i = 0; i < holder.childNodes.length; ++i) {
                switch (holder.childNodes[i].className) {
                    case "left":
                        holder.childNodes[i].innerHTML = timeArr[key][0];
                        break;
                    case "right":
                        holder.childNodes[i].innerHTML = timeArr[key][4];
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            CountBack(myDiv, secs - 1);
        }, 990);
    } else {
        document.getElementById(myDiv).innerHTML = "Auction Over";
    }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понял, а где тут разделено? Мне нужно разделить не на часы, минуты, секунды. В вопросе я написал "Например 16 минут - это 1 в одном диве и 6 в другом." То есть количество секунд надо разделить на две части, количество минут на две и т.д.

Comment: Видимо, невнимательно прочитал вопрос... Исправил решение.

Comment: А почему если оставить только <div id="timer1">[clock1]</div>, убрав <p>..</p>..., таймер перестаёт отображаться?

Comment: Потому что скрипту некуда значения записывать. Учел это и переписал решение. Теперь все нужные элементы создаются автоматически.

Comment: Обновил свой ответ. Понятнее объяснить уже не смогу. Вот НОВАЯ ссылка на пример http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/BDtJy/4/

Comment: В последний раз отредактировал свой ответ. Написал 2(!!!) варианта реализации скрипта. Выбирайте тот, который вам понятнее.

Comment: Как и обещал, рейтинг ВАШ! Спасибо!